# Where is Job Priority in YARN UI?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

In MR1 the UI had a nice column showing the job priority.  In YARN UI I can't find this. Where is it?  Also I'm not even sure when I use `mapred.job.priority` it's changing the job priority as the jobs with higher priority don't seem to run as quickly as I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not implemented in the current schedulers, AFAIK: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-1963